# What is the name of the mentioned component?

Tags: sensor, connector, components

I have a pair of GRDE GL019 earbuds. One of those cheap ones, but fits me really well and has a great sound , hence i am taking so much pain to repair it.

I want to replace the mentioned/marked connectors in the picture, but dont know what are those called, and where can i find them online. These points are for contact charging the buds. BAsically, when i close the box the buds charge. So my guess is, there is some kind of spring mechanism inside those connectors whcih dont work anymore.. I can only see J1 and J2 (guessing those are just codes for connectors).

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

enter image description here[image]

Comment: These components are called "pogo pins". You can find them online on Mouser/Farnell/DigiKey for example.

Comment: Adding to Pierre's comment. They come in many sizes, so you will want to carefully measure the ones you are replacing.

Comment: If you push on them and they spring back, then they're probably fine.  Make sure it's not something stupid-simple (meaning: something that **I would miss**) like dirt on the contacts -- particularly if there's a well in the earbud for the contact that may collect dirt or lint.

Answer (score 2):

I have used lots of such connectors in my previous projects, we call it
Pogo pin.

Answer (score 1):

The official term is "spring loaded connector".